# Could not resolve all files for configuration

Tags: android, maven, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-architecture-lifecycle

I just implemented the `Android Architecture Library` in my Android project, everything works fine when i build the app gradle module, but i can't test it on a physical/emulator device this shows up on the message gradle build

Error:Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugAnnotationProcessorClasspath'.

> Could not resolve android.arch.lifecycle:compiler:1.0.0.
>     Required by:
>         project :app
>   No cached version of android.arch.lifecycle:compiler:1.0.0 available for offline mode.
>   No cached version of android.arch.lifecycle:compiler:1.0.0 available for offline mode.
>   No cached version of android.arch.lifecycle:compiler:1.0.0 available for offline mode.
>   No cached version of android.arch.lifecycle:compiler:1.0.0 available for offline mode.
>   No cached version of android.arch.lifecycle:compiler:1.0.0 available for offline mode.

I already have my offline mode unchecked in Settings and Power saving mode already unchecked.

Please help me out.

Comment: Faced with a same problem? Did you have any solution already?

Comment: @DenisMakovsky sure check my answer. Hope it helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stupid mistake but i forgot to uncheck my offline gradle in settings.